# JQuery dialog as input

Tags: jquery, input

I'm not very used to working with jquery dialogs and stuff. 
So this is kind of a newbie question.

At this moment I'm using the prompt to get a reply from the user in my SharePoint.

```
var answer = dialog("Type the text you want to display in the email.");
```

But then my input is limited.

Can anyone help me?

Addition.
I was now able to insert my dialog. But I'm not able to display it.

This is how I insert it:

```
if ($("#dialogSendMail").length) {

}
else {
    $("#DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent").after("<div id='dialogSendMail' title='Enter mail body'> <label for='mailBody'>Type the text you want to display in the email:</label><p><input type='text' id='mailBody' name='mailBody'></p></div>");
}
```

And this is how I try to display it:

```
        var answer ="";

    $( "#dialogSendMail" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:350,
            width:650,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen : false,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Send Mail",
                    click: $.noop,
                    type: "submit",
                    form: "myForm"
                },
                {
                    text: "Close",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

But when I run my code, it doesn't display the dialog.
Additionally i'm trying to find a way to get the response from the textbox.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Dejan.S : Showing my answer is not the problem. That I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such dialog for pure jquery, use jquery UI instead.
What is your real question?

```
$( "form" ).dialog({
    open: function() {
        // On open, hide the original submit button
        $( this ).find( "[type=submit]" ).hide();
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Find",
            click: $.noop,
            type: "submit",
            form: "myForm" 
        },
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9ff3gjs/1/

Comment: your code looks like good but in your code js and html are together in html window, i think this is better way :
http://jsfiddle.net/ent1c3d/s9ff3gjs/2/