# Display JQuery dialog using a JS-file

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, dialog

I was able to insert my dialog. But I'm not able to display it.

This is how I insert it:

```
if ($("#dialogSendMail").length) {

}
else {
    $("#DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent").after("<div id='dialogSendMail' title='Enter mail body'> <label for='mailBody'>Type the text you want to display in the email:</label><p><input type='text' id='mailBody' name='mailBody'></p></div>");
}
```

And this is how I try to display it:

```
var answer ="";

$( "#dialogSendMail" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:350,
        width:650,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen : false,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Send Mail",
                click: $.noop,
                type: "submit",
                form: "myForm"
            },
            {
                text: "Close",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

But when I run my code, it doesn't display the dialog. Additionally i'm trying to find a way to get the response from the textbox.

Can anyone help me?

Also see : [JQuery dialog as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365758/jquery-dialog-as-input/30367829)

In my js-file I also have to following line:

```
answer = GetEmailBody();
```

End the GetEmailBody() calls the method you see higher up to display the dialog.

My code now looks as follows:

```
function GetEmailBody() {
    $("#dialogSendMail").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 350,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Send Mail",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    answer = "This is just a test message.";
                    SendEmail();
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Close",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    SendEmail();
                }
            }
        ]
    });

}

function SendEmail()
{
    xmlHttpReq.open("GET", _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/SendDocuments/MyCustomHandler.ashx?ItemsArray=" + fileRefArray + "&IdsArray=" + idArray + "&EmailText=" + answer, false);
    xmlHttpReq.send(null);

    var yourJSString = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
    alert(yourJSString);
}
```

But now I get a message that an app should be opened on my computer.
This was not necessary when I didn't go through the dialog.
Then it called my ASHX-file which did the sending of the mail.

Comment: You need to bind the event to that.

Comment: There is no real event, I think.
I'm doing it in SharePoint. On the click of a button there, I need to send an email. The dialog is there so the users can enter an additional message to add to the email.

Comment: What about to just set `autoOpen` to true? [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/catsjwzy/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve my problem:

function GetEmailBody() {
    $("#dialogSendMail").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 350,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Send Mail",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    answer = $(mailBody)[0].innerText;
                    xmlHttpReq.open("GET", _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/SendDocuments/MyCustomHandler.ashx?ItemsArray=" + fileRefArray + "&IdsArray=" + idArray + "&EmailText=" + answer, false);
                    xmlHttpReq.send(null);

```
                var yourJSString = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
                alert(yourJSString);
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                SendEmail();
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

}

```
function SendEmail()
{
    xmlHttpReq.open("GET", _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/SendDocuments/MyCustomHandler.ashx?ItemsArray=" + fileRefArray + "&IdsArray=" + idArray + "&EmailText=" + answer, false);
    xmlHttpReq.send(null);

    var yourJSString = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
    alert(yourJSString);
}
```

And this works as I hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Set autoOpen to true:

```
$( "#dialogSendMail" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:350,
    width:650,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen : true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Send Mail",
            click: $.noop,
            type: "submit",
            form: "myForm"
        },
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: OK, the auto-open worked. I'm now getting my dialog. But I still want to retrieve the text I type, so I can use it as text in my email.